# Is there a "refresh" ability on an activity?

Tags: android, refresh

I have an activity, inside the onCreate() method there are some instances and some basic operation.. now i want to refresh (call onCreate() again??? ) my activity on particular button click so is this possible??

i have done it by this way..

this.onCreate(null);

but not works well
Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put all these operations in one method, then call this method on the button click and `onCreate`..

Answer (score 0):

Just move your logic out from `onCreate` into another method, say `init`. Then call `init` from both `onCreate` and your button click handler.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own method and wrap the code from onCreate to this method.
Call this method in onCreate and as well where ever you want(like in your case on button click).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to restart the current activity for this.

Here is the code for restarting activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The better ooption is to put your code inside `onResume()`. As `onResume()` will be called everytime your Activity is in Foreground and also you can call it directly using `onResume()` on your Button Click Event.

Answer (score 0):

option 1:

it is always better to keep the logic outside the oncreate() function and then call the logic from oncreate function as well as activity refresh button.

Option 2:

finish the activity and start the same activity.